# Number of k-tuples of subsets the intersection of which contains m elements

Tags: combinatorics

If we have a k-tuple $\langle A_1,...,A_k\rangle$ where $A_i \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$ for $1\leq i \leq k$.

How many k-tuples exist such that $\lvert A_1 \cap ... \cap A_k \rvert = m$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the $m$ values who appear in the final intersection.  These must be present in all $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_k$

> There are $\binom{n}{m}$ ways of making this choice

For the remaining $n-m$ values, choose which subset of $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_k$ they appear in noting that they may not appear in all simultaneously (*else they would have appeared in the final intersection*).

> There are $2^k-1$ ways to make this choice for each of the $n-m$ values respectively

Apply rule of product and conclude.

> $$\binom{n}{m}(2^k-1)^{n-m}$$